# How to allow/force text to overflow into adjacent non empty cell?

Tags: excel, calc

I'm using Calc, but a solution for Excel would be helpful too.
I have text in one cell A that overflows to the next cell B. When I put something in B, text stops overflowing from A, although B's content is right-aligned, and text overflowing from A wouldn't actually cover any B content.

How to force A to overflow, even when B is no longer empty ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do it as you describe.

The only thing you could do is adjust column width to accommodate the extra text, but you'll be left with extra white space for some cells if text length varies significantly.